# Can Flask app handle http requests if APscheduler is running using BackgroundScheduler

Tags: python-2.7, flask, apscheduler

My flask app sends text SMSes every 5 minutes.

My question is will my app be able to respond to http requests that it gets if I use BackgroundScheduler to run my job after every 5 minutes.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, I've tried and tested it and it works. Just write a sample code to verify if it would work on your PC.